# Big Blue Button (BBB) checksum generation for Zapier webhooks

Tags: checksum, zapier, bigbluebutton

I'm trying to make calls to my BBB server through Zapier webhhoks but I can't correctly calculate the checksum that must be appended to any call.

I read the documentation (https://docs.bigbluebutton.org/dev/webhooks.html#callback-format) but I can't understand the exact string upon which the checksum is generated (there's a point at the end of the paragraph where they say "And convert it to a string like in the example below:" but I see no example string afterwards)

I looked at how bbb calls should look like here: https://mconf.github.io/api-mate/
I've read the checksum should be generated in this way: sha1(++)
I then assumed it could be something like: sha1(https://my.server.com/bigbluebutton/api/create?+meetingID=testmeeting&name=testmeeting&record=false+mysharedsecretkey)

It doesn't work though.
Am I missing something?
Any example of how that string between the two brackets should look like?

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.bigbluebutton.org/dev/api.html#usage

createname=Test+Meeting&meetingID=abc123&attendeePW=111222&moderatorPW=333444639259d4-9dd8-4b25-bf01-95f9567eaf4b

this is what gets hashed to create the checksum that needs to be added.  notice no server URL

Answer (score 0):

I code a function to convert Unicode characters to bigbluebutton readable so checksum can work perfectly. it is python code but the same concept can be implemented in any other language.

```
@staticmethod
def decode_for_bigbluebutton(string_to_convert):
    decoded_string_to_convert = str(string_to_convert.encode('utf-8')).replace("b'", "").replace("'", "").replace("\\", "%")
    list_of_unicode_characters = re.findall(r'%\w+', decoded_string_to_convert)
    list_of_converted_to_upper_case_utf8 = list()
    for unicode_character in list_of_unicode_characters:
        list_of_converted_to_upper_case_utf8.append(unicode_character.replace("x", "").upper())
    for item_index in range(len(list_of_converted_to_upper_case_utf8)):
        decoded_string_to_convert = decoded_string_to_convert.replace(list_of_unicode_characters[item_index],
                                                                      list_of_converted_to_upper_case_utf8[item_index])
    decoded_string_to_convert = decoded_string_to_convert.replace(" ", "%20")
    return decoded_string_to_convert
```